# How should I insert data to MYSQL database from a HTML form?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I know that node runs on the backend and while it's not a problem to connect to the SQL database via the server.js file, I cannot understand how I could do that from within a js linked to a form element (that's definitely client-side js, and I cannot make the connection from inside there). I know this maybe confusing, so I would very grateful for any help.
I am a beginner, so please keep it simple. Youtube videos are also fine. Thanks in advance :)

```
    const mysql = require("mysql");
    //create connection to sql database
    const connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "localhost",
        user: "root",
        password: "",  
        database: "blog",
      });

      connection.query('select * from posts', () => {
          console.log('done');
      })
//this works when i put it inside server.js (using express) but not inside some other file- says cannot use require.
```

Comment: Your client-side JS should definitely _not_ be able to connect directly to your SQL database.  It should make an XHR request to an endpoint exposed by your backend server code, which takes the request and make the appropriate update to the SQL database.  This is what web backends are for.  Providing _direct_ access to your SQL db from the FE would be like building a bank without tellers, and just opening the vault so people could go place and add money as they saw fit and assume they'll keep track of it themselves.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, made it work- kind of! 
I tried making an end-point for the form & used body-parser as the middleware (whatever that means), and it seems to give whatever was in the form.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Plain and simple , this is the initialization of the database connection. In order to use this connection object in other files you need to export it or to incorporate it in "req" object supported by express. I suggest that in the end of the file you add

```
module.exports ={
     connection : mysql.createConnection(config) 
}
```

and then use the connection object to make queries elsewhere.
Apart from this i would suggest that you start using Sequelize since it is a powerful ORM for nodejs. First learn sql logic and test your queries directly in the database through Mysql workbench , pgadmin , etc and then dive deep into sequelize documentation to take yourself to the next level. Hope this answer will solve your problem!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The question is asking how to do this from client-side JS, not from Node.js + Express. The already have it working for Node.js.